# Youtube API Node.js quickstart not working: "The API returned an error: Error: invalid_grant"

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I followed the tutorial [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs), including installing the libraries `googleapis` and `google-auth-library`. I believe I followed the instructions for setting up the credentials properly to my best ability, but I lack the experience to know for sure.

I was unable to exactly follow the tutorial, specifically this line:

> e. Select the application type Other, enter the name "YouTube Data API Quickstart", and click the Create button.

because the drop down selection box had no "Other" type.

I had a project using this system working in the past, but it suddenly stopped working. I had not used the program for months, so it is possible something happened in the meantime, but I also absentmindedly revoked the program's access to my Google account.

I am not using the same credentials as before it broke -- in the developer console, I not only deleted the old credentials and downloaded brand-new ones, I created a new project altogether.

Here is an image of the credential:

[image: OAuth 2.0 Client IDs: Name: Desktop Client 1, Creation date: Nov 2, 2020, Type: Desktop]

Of course, I downloaded and renamed the client_secret JSON as instructed.

Here are my project files:

[image: In one folder, in a WebStorm project: client_secret.json, package.json, package-lock.json, quickstart.js]

Since I directly copied the code, I have not tried changing it, though I did look through it to make sure there were no IDs I needed to copy in or anything of the sort.

I tried looking through [this article](https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35), but I had no idea where to even begin the stated debugging processes, as my only experience with OAuth, Node.js, and the YouTube API is this project, and I don't even understand how I got it working originally.

If anyone has any ideas on ways I could try fixing this, or more thorough instructions on how I could begin debugging, I would be immensely grateful.

If relevant at all, I am using the WebStorm IDE.

Screenshot of the terminal:

[image: Image of terminal with 2 lines: node quickstart.js, and the error response as seen in the title]

Comment: Usually the API returns an `error_description` with more information. Do you know what that says?

Comment: The article [Google OAuth “invalid_grant” nightmare — and how to fix it](https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35) is of good quality, yet, a bit hard to digest. Since your're running your program under Node.js, I suggest to select from the drop down box the entry `Other UI (e.g. Windows, CLI tool)`.

Comment: @TreyGriffith The line "The API returned an error: Error: invalid_grant" is the only thing the console says before terminating the program. Do I have to specifically request the error_description in any way?

Comment: I meant the down down box that allows you to select the *application type*.

Comment: @stvar The Application type dropdown box has no "Other UI" option. The types are:
Web application, Android, Chrome app, iOS, TVs and Limited Input Devices, Desktop app, and Universal Windows Platform (UWP). Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Then select `Desktop app`.

Comment: @stvar Unfortunately, Desktop app is the application type I was already using. I have tried using Web application in the past as well, but that also didn't work.

Comment: But you're running something like `node quickstart.js`, isn't it?

Comment: @stvar Yes. I will attach an image of the console to the original post.

Comment: Then your app type cannot be neither of the types that you listed above, except `Desktop app`.

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on without seeing your code, but is it possible that your code is using a token that is from your old client? The fact that it's not prompting you with an authorization URL tells me that it thinks it already has a token on disk. But if that token is revoked, expired, or associated with the old client, it won't work.

Comment: @TreyGriffith The code can be seen in the link to the quickstart. I copied it exactly and made no changes.

Are you talking about the authentication information I get from the downloaded json? I always make sure to remove the old one from the folder first.

Comment: That code (in the quickstart) stores the refresh token in a file called `youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json`, so make sure that's deleted.